# Trying to copy data from one place in firebase to another. Getting database path error

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Here is my current database structure:

```
{
 "Classes" : {
    "aa" : {
        "classID" : "aa",
        "className" : "aa",
        "days" : [ "tuesday", "thursday" ],
        "startTime" : "1010",
        "teacherID" : "XiYeok0F0zMtZT7qRVeEXRilWEs1"
    },
    "test101" : {
       "classID" : "test101",
       "className" : "testing classes",
       "days" : [ "monday", "wednesday", "friday" ],
       "gpsLocation" : "999",
       "startTime" : "1010",
       "teacherID" : "y4cLhvIGvkcErHPTAXsglb0rXcl1"
    }
},
 "Users" : {
   "jYi10gDlWEcoLgJ6xgRHQ2qeAxI2" : {
     "classList" : [ {
         "className" : "Ignore me"} ],
     "fname" : "Rick",
     "id" : "jYi10gDlWEcoLgJ6xgRHQ2qeAxI2",
     "lname" : "Ross"
},
   "reg6pCXft3Uvlg87VxXFnEBQ6Lt1" : {
      "classList" : [ {
      "className" : "Ignore me"} ],
      "fname" : "name",
      "id" : "reg6pCXft3Uvlg87VxXFnEBQ6Lt1",
      "lname" : "name"
},
  "y4cLhvIGvkcErHPTAXsglb0rXcl1" : {
      "classList" : [ {
      "className" : "Ignore me"} ],
      "fname" : "name",
      "id" : "y4cLhvIGvkcErHPTAXsglb0rXcl1",
      "lname" : "name"
}
}
}
```

What I am trying to do is copy the user that is open in the picture, and paste that information with the same formatting into the class "test101" but in a node called roster.

I have seen plenty with value change listeners but I dont see how that will apply here if i am not changing the values but just need to read them into code and then put them elsewhere.

here is my code so far:

```
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.Query;

public class Join_Class extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_join_class);
    final FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
    final DatabaseReference fbRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

    final EditText etClassID = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etClassID);
    Button joinBut  = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bJoin);
    final String userID = fbRef.child("Users").child(user.getUid()).getKey();


    joinBut.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){
            final String classID = etClassID.getText().toString().trim();
                if(fbRef.child("Classes").child(classID).getKey() == classID){
                    //get user id node information
                    //put into arraylist in class specified
                    //not asking you to write this for me, maybe what to use 
                    //for the task
                }
            sendTo(Main__Menu.class);
        }
    });

}

private void sendTo(Class s){
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, s);
    startActivity(intent);
}
}
```

Comment: What line is giving you what specific error? Also: please learn to paste the JSON as text and not as a screenshot. You can easily get the text by clicking the Export JSON button in your Firebase Database console. Having the JSON as text makes it searchable, allows us to easily use it to test with your actual data and use it in our answer and in general is just a Good Thing to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your code in OnClickListenr

```
fbRef.child("Classes").child(classID).getKey()
```

In my opinion, the proper way to do your query is:

```
// Filter the object (Classes) you would like to deal with
Query query = fbRef.child("Classes").orderByChild(classID).equalTo(classID);

// Then add a listener
query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {

        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if (dataSnapshot.exists()){
                // classID matched, do your stuffs
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
  });
```

Hope my answer can help you

Comment: but if I am not changing any values in the database, will the onDataChange() be ran?

Comment: yes, it will run even you only wanted to retrieve the data

Comment: Just feel free to use this listener. And one thing very interesting is that "onDataChange" seems not to listen the events happened on your app, it listens to your firebase database. The advantages to use this listener is whenever the data in your database changes, the value of UI (say TextView) on your app will be changed in the same time.

Comment: You're welcome. Firebase is really a helpful backend service and it provides lots of feature. I'm still exploring it now :P

Comment: Yeah i thought that it would only grab a snapshot once the data changed from what it already was in the database. but i guess when the listener is applied, the first time it "sees" the data counts as a change.

Comment: Yeah. It confused me as well when I use Firebase at my very first time. But I get used to it very soon :)